# How to parse an input according to column's variables in bash

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, awk

I need help to parse an input like this.

```
192.168.0.168: 1
192.168.0.158: 0
192.168.0.198: 0
192.168.0.148: 0
192.168.0.158: 1
192.168.0.168: 0
```

If there is 1 in second column of any ip, I want to delete the row which have 0 in second column and same ip in first column. So my output should be like this.

```
192.168.0.168: 1
192.168.0.198: 0
192.168.0.148: 0
192.168.0.158: 1
```

I guess It can be done by using awk, sed etc. but I have no idea how to do that. I hope I could explain my question correctly. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '
    { 
        ips[ $1 ] = ( ips[ $1 ] == 1 ) ? 1 : $2 
    } 
    END { 
        for ( ip in ips ) { 
            print ip, ips[ ip ] 
        } 
    }
' infile
```

That yields (output could be unordered):

```
192.168.0.168: 1
192.168.0.198: 0
192.168.0.148: 0
192.168.0.158: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
cat -n file | 
sort -k2,2 -k3,3nr | 
sed ':a;$!N;/^\s*\S*\s*\(\S*\)\s*1\s*\n.*\1/s/\n.*0\s*//;ta;P;D' | 
sort -n | 
sed 's/^\s*\S*\s*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -nae '$h{ $F[0] } += $F[1]
           }{
           print "$k ", $v ? 1 : 0, "\n" while ($k, $v) = each %h'
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of `sort`s should do:

```
sort file -r | sort -u -k1,1
```

The former sort makes sure the lines are ordered so that lines with 1 on the second column will come first for every IP.

The latter sort will keep only the first entry for each IP: `-u` -> unique, `-k1,1` -> first column only.

Comment: To preserve line order you can use same trick that _potong's_ answer uses. First number the lines and with `cat -n`, and post sort on first column: `cat -n infile | sort -k2 -r | sort -u -k2,2 | sort -n | cut -f2-`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

**Functional approach (haskell programming language):**

```
-- function that having the two sublists with '0' and '1' ips,
-- filters and puts into   the '1' 
-- sublist all the '0' ips that are not included in '1'

fil [] result = result
fil (x: xs) result | (init x `elem` (map init result)) == False = fil xs (x:result)
            | otherwise = fil xs result


-- function that filters '0' and '1' sublists
getsublist alist character = filter (\x-> (last x) == character) alist



> let a = ["192.168.0.168: 1", "192.168.0.158: 0", "192.168.0.198: 0", "192.168.0.148: 0", "192.168.0.158: 1", "192.168.0.168: 0"]

> let b = getsublist a '0'

> let c = getsublist a '1'

> fil b c
```

**Output:**

```
["192.168.0.148: 0","192.168.0.198: 0","192.168.0.168: 1","192.168.0.158: 1"]
```